# SQL - Exclude values of a column which meet a requirement at least once

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, join

There are the two tables `Client` and `Stock`:

```
Table Client
    Column IDC       (primary key, int, not null)

Table Stock
    Column IDS       (primary key, int, not null)
    Column IDC       (int, not null)
    Column Type      (bit, not null)
    Column Price     (decimal(10,2), null)
```

They are to be taken as connected by `Client.IDC = Stock.IDC`.

Getting `IDC` of clients with `Type = 1` and `Price not NULL` is trivial. However, it's not trivial to me to get the list of the remaining `IDC`. The following attempt does not deliver correct list of `IDC`:

```
SELECT [Client].[IDC]
FROM [Client] LFEFT JOIN [Stock] on [Client].[IDC] = [Stock].[IDC]
WHERE NOT([Stock].[Type] = 1 AND [Stock].[Price] IS NOT NULL)
```

This statement returns some `IDC` which should be excluded as there are, for them, indeed rows with `Type = 0` but also other rows with `Type = 1` and `Price not NULL`. How should I proceed to get `IDC` which have no row with `Type = 1` and `Price not NULL` at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the condition in the `ON` clause.

This means that the condition in the `ON` clause will filter the rows in table `Stock` before  joining with `Client`.

```
SELECT [Client].[IDC]
FROM [Client] 
     LEFT JOIN [Stock] 
         on [Client].[IDC] = [Stock].[IDC]
              AND [Stock].[Type] = 1 
              AND [Stock].[Price] IS NOT NULL
WHERE [Stock].[IDC] IS NULL
```

This can also be convert using `NOT EXISTS`

```
SELECT [Client].[IDC]
FROM [Client] c
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM [Stock] s
    WHERE c.[IDC] = s.IDC
              AND s.[Type] = 1 
              AND s.[Price] IS NOT NULL
)
```